# PHP Warning: imagejpeg(): Invalid 2nd parameter, it must a filename or a stream

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código

```
imagejpeg($new_im, false, 70);
```

Então retorna o erro:

> PHP Warning:  imagejpeg(): Invalid 2nd parameter, it must a filename
>   or a stream in
>   /home/sisv2/sis_adm/version/demo/includes/control/mooeditable_functions.ctrl.php
>   on line 151

Comment: O segundo argumento deveria ser o nome do arquivo, http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consulte a documentação do método e verá que o segundo argumento deve ser o nome do arquivo. Ele e o terceiro são opcionais, mas se passados devem ser de acordo com o oesperado pela função.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

[]s